# SQL Server: Min/Max/Percentiles

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get the count, min, max, and some percentiles (10th, 25th, 50th, 75th, 90th) of base salaries for each master job title.

[image]

I'm getting the following error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'dbo.ps_employee.Base' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: PERCENTILE_DISC  it isn't aggregate function like COUNT/MIN/MAX/AVG(column). This exception is generated by columns used by this functions and which aren't used for GROUPing: e.base. Simplest solution could be to create a separate query to compute percentiles.

Comment: does removing (ORDER BY e.base) change the business logic?

Comment: No, I thought the ORDER BY was required by the PERCENTILE_DISC function?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use the following query to get the percentiles. I used a separate one for count/min/max/average.

```
SELECT DISTINCT mj.title, 
    PERCENTILE_DISC(.1)  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY e.base) 
                         OVER (PARTITION BY mj.title) AS '10th', 
    PERCENTILE_DISC(.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY e.base)
                         OVER (PARTITION BY mj.title) AS '25th', 
    PERCENTILE_DISC(.5)  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY e.base)
                         OVER (PARTITION BY mj.title) AS '50th', 
    PERCENTILE_DISC(.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY e.base) 
                         OVER (PARTITION BY mj.title) AS '75th', 
    PERCENTILE_DISC(.9)  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY e.base) 
                         OVER (PARTITION BY mj.title) AS '90th' 
FROM dbo.ps_employee e 
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.ps_jobs j on e.title = j.job 
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.ps_masterjobs mj ON j.masterID = mj.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must include all non-aggregated items in your select list, at the bottom in the `GROUP BY` section.

> Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

Add `over (partition by title)` in your `count`, `min`, `max` and `avg` functions while also adding base to your group by functions. This will allow you to have all the values in a single row set but you will have duplicate rows in the output

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `OVER (PARTITION BY NULL)` to your min and max functions.  It worked for me.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
        MIN(metric) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL) AS MIN_metric
        ,PERCENTILE_CONT(0.01) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY metric) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL) AS metric_P01
        ,MAX(metric) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL) AS MAX_metric
    FROM mytable
```